# Curves blow-up and Hurwitz formula.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have this curve $C =$ { $[X,Y,Z] \in \mathbb{P^2C} | Y^3Z = X^4 - X^2Z^2$}.

I've found that it's singular in $[0,0,0]$. So, I have to blow up this point. I don't know if $[0,0,1]$ is a base point (How to find one ?), but I've considered the equation for the affine curve related which is $Y^3 = X^4 - X^2$. Then for one chart of the blow-up I put $Y = ut$ and $X = t$ and I obtain $u^2(ut^3 - u^2 +1)$. I take $ut^3 - u^2 + 1 = 0$ which is $ut^3 -u^2w^2 + w^4$ in the projective space (Is this the curve without singularities I obtain blowing up the singular point ?)

If it is correct I've found a Riemann surface related to the curve $C$, on this surface I consider the meromorphic function $f = \dfrac{X}{Y}$.
Is it possible that f has a zero in $[0,0,1]$ and a pole in $[0,1,0]$ both of order one ?

I can consider the holomorphic function $G : C{\setminus}[0,0,0] \longrightarrow \mathbb{P^1C}$ which sends the poles in $\infty$. I have then in $mult_{[1,0,0]}G =1 = mult_{[0,1,0]}G$.

This Riemann surface has genus 3 by Plücker's formula.
So I have to verify Hurwitz's formula $$2g(C{\setminus}[0,0,0]) -2 = degG(2g(\mathbb{P^1} - 2) + \sum_p (mult_pG - 1).$$
So, I don't know how to compute the degree of G and if G has any branch points.

Sorry for the long question but I'm a little bit confused. Thank you.

Comment: 1) (0,0,0) does not define a point in $\Bbb P^2$. 

2) What do you mean by a base point ? A base point is usually associated to a linear system.

Comment: Sorry I should have misunderstood something maybe the singularity in in [0,0,1], well my aim was to blow-up the projective curve. I don't know if it's the same considering one of the coordinates be one and blow up the resulting  affine curve. I was thinking the base point as the only point in which this can be done.

Comment: Keep in mind that $(0,0,0)$ is a singular point of the affine cone over the projective curve, but that point is systematically removed in the definition of projective variety.

Comment: Regarding what to blowup, eyeballing it looks to me like $(0,0,1)$ is indeed going to be singular (double check with partials though!). And yes, you can blowup an affine patch containing the singular point; blowing up is a local process.

Comment: Ok Thank you ! So I have to substitue Z with Z -1 for the blow up ? Or how I've proceeded is correct ?

Comment: You did the blow up correctly. You don't need to take the projective closure of the curve. $ut^3  - u^2 + 1 = 0$ has gradient $(t^3 - 2u, 2ut^2)$ so the only point where this vanishes is $(0,0)$ which is not on the affine curve, i.e you curve is indeed smooth after one blow-up. I would say that your curve is of degree $4$ with one singularity so it's a rational curve, i.e $C$ is birational to $\Bbb P^1$. On the other hand, if $X/Y$ has one zero and one pole of order one and is defined everywhere it would gives an isomorphism $C \cong \Bbb P^1$. And indeed it's not defined at $[0:0:1]$.

Comment: So everything looks correct except the computation of the genus (smooth curve of degree $d$ have genus $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$ and singularity decrease the genus.)

Comment: Thank you very much @N.H.  for your help!  And how do I compute the degree of G and find the branch points ? Maybe the degree is 2 ? I haven't the slightest idea about the branch points maybe I have to compute the gradient ?

Comment: I am not sure about exact definition of $G$. But if you have a morphism $G : C \to \Bbb P^1$, indeed branch points are exactly when the derivatives vanishes. For the degree of $G$, pick any point $b \in \Bbb P^1$ and compute $|G^{-1}(b)|$. If for all $z \in G^{-1}(b)$, if $G'(z) \neq 0$ then $\deg G = |G^{-1}(b)|$.
Else, you need to compute ramification index $e_z$ and then $\deg(G) =  |G^{-1}(b)| + \sum_{z}e_z$ where the sum is over all $z \in C$ with $G(z) = b$.

Comment: Well thanks again @N.H ! Now computing using Hurwitz formula on the LHS I get 2 and  the$$ RHS = -2deg(G) + \sum_z e_z$$ now the degree of G is 1 for that I think I'm sure and taking the derivatives in $x$ and $y$ of $dfrac{x}{y} $I get only one zero of order one and this would bring a value of -1 on the LHS which is definetely uncorrect .

Comment: Ok, I can try to check the computation by myself a bit later, could please say how $G$ is defined exactly ?

Comment: $G =\dfrac{X}{Y} when Y \neq 0 $,  $\qquad \infty$ otherwise and defined from $C{\setminus}(singular point) \qquad$ to the Riemann sphere.

Comment: I just realized now that you will have some problems applying Riemann-Hurwitz formula here, because you have a singular point. There is a version of HR for singular curves here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827014/genus-of-the-curve-y2-x3x2-via-riemann-hurwitz (here $\delta$ should be 1) but it gives you the arithmetic genus, defined in term of the Hilbert polynomial $h_C$.

Comment: Ok Thank you again ! I appreciate it! Now I've asked a new question over the matter

Comment: Perfect, good luck !