# Singular strange curves over algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ must be lines (Hartshorne IV.3.8b)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider the projective $n$-space $\mathbb{P}^n$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$ (e.g. $k=\mathbb{C}$), and let $X$ be an integral closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $1$. For a nonsingular closed point $p\in X$, there is a unique line $L\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $T_p(L)=T_p(X)$ as subspaces of $T_p(\mathbb{P}^n)$, and we say $L$ is the tangent line of $X$ at $p$. We say $X$ is a **strange curve** in $\mathbb{P^n}$, if there is a point $q\in\mathbb{P}^n$ such that for every nonsingular closed point $p$ of $X$, the tangent line of $X$ at $p$ passes through $q$. I want to show that, if $X$ is a strange curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$, then $X$ must be a line in $\mathbb{P}^n$, i.e., a complete intersection of $n-1$ hyperplanes.

This is the exercise IV.3.8(b) in R. Hartshorne's book *Algebraic Geometry*, and Hartshorne gave a proof for nonsingular case in theorem 3.9 of chapter IV. I first wanted to imitate the proof in theorem 3.9, but it seems that $X$ cannot always be embedded in $\mathbb{P}^3$, since there may exist bad singularity $p$ with (Zariski) tangent space of dimension $>3$.

Now I try to reduce this problem to the nonsingular case. My first attempt is to resolute the singularities of $X$ by normalization, but it does not preserve the "strange" property of curve (since it depends on the specified embedding $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$). And my second attempt is to show that a strange curve has already been nonsingular (by e.g. showing it is of arithmetic genus $0$: using [Hurwitz's formula for singular curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1827125), I can show that the normalization of $X$ is of genus $0$ when considering the case $n=3$), but I have no idea to proceed and does not know how to use the assumption $\mathrm{char}\,k=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is using the fact that projection from a point which is on $T_pX$ for nonsingular $p$ makes $p$ a ramification point, i.e. $\Omega_{X/\pi(X)}$ has nonzero stalk at $p$. If you project from the point where all the tangent lines to the nonsingular points meet and the image $\pi(X)$ is a curve, you have a map of one-dimensional integral schemes over $k$ which is ramified at every nonsingular point. But this is impossible for a dominant map of one-dimensional integral schemes over $k$ in characteristic zero: the sheaf of relative differentials $\Omega_{X/\pi(X)}$ is coherent and zero at the generic point (because the stalk there is the module of differentials for the finite *separable* extension of function fields, hence zero) and therefore the support of $\Omega_{X/\pi(X)}$ must be a proper closed subset, i.e. finitely many points. So the projection of the curve must be a point, implying that the curve is a line.